# On image hover, display title/alt tag in center

Tags: html, hover

I'm looking for a way so that when I hover over an image, the title or alt tag is displayed in the center of the image (fading in/out), with the image also lowered in opacity.

I've looked around quite a bit but most javascript plugins I find create a tool tip and it's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the images need to stay in a simple ul list, no extra divs or anything wrapping around each image. They will also use the rel attr for shadowbox or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
$('ul li img').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('opacity','.5');
        var a = $(this).attr('alt');
        $(this).parent().append('<div class="title">' + a + '</div>');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('opacity','1');
        $(this).next().remove('.title');
    }
);
```

(*Quick and dirty jQuery could definitely be improved*)

**CSS**

```
ul li img{
    position:relative;
}

.title{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    right:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:red;
}
```

(*CSS could also be improved... but this gives you an idea*)

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dgKne/

Comment: Thank you, this works brilliantly. I just need to figure out how to make the css put the title in the center of each image. With the CSS provided it sits in the center of the page. I've got it to the bottom left of each image ok at the moment.

If it make .title relative I can position it in the center of the image, but it makes all the other images move out of position when hovered (it's a grid of square images).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a general description of how you can approach in solving this problem using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/):

1) Put an image in a div and give this div class (example: altHover) 
2) On hover, first pick alt tag and store it in variable: `var title = $("em").attr("title");` 
3) in the same hover function, make new div inside hovered div and print alt tag inside it:

```
$(".altHover").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append($("<div class='altText'>" + title +"</div>"));
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find(".altText").remove();
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this by having the images just in a simple ul list. Reason being, the client shall be using CMS to add images to the page, and the way it's set up will not add the divs in that manner.

Should have mentioned that in the first post, sorry.

Comment: It is possible. Just change part in .append to select what you need. If you don't manage to handle it post html code here

Answer (score 0):

You could use what ile has, but instead of adding a div, you could use addClass. Just use li as the hoverable object.

```
$("li.picture").hover(
    function(){
        $(".selected_result").removeClass("selected_result");
        $(this).addClass("selected_result");
    }
);
```

I am not a pro javascript person, but this would give you an idea.