# Show title tag on hover inside img

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Hi I need show a Title tag of img inside img.

Like this example http://jsfiddle.net/51csqs0b/

```css
.image {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.image img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.image:after, .image:before {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:after {
    content:'\A';
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.image:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:0;
    padding:4px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.image:hover:after, .image:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div data-content="Here is a caption" class="image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<hr>
    
<div data-content="Different caption here..." class="image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

But i don't want use a div before img.

```
<a href="#"><img class="" title="TITLE NEED SHOW ON HOVER" src=""/></a>
```

It's possible to show up?
Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried already? Can you share your code?

Comment: related if not a dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661498/on-image-hover-display-title-alt-tag-in-center

Comment: @RST Hi, yes the answers down work well can you check that code

Comment: @web-tiki yes this it's other good way. Thanks for share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all thing I can do:

add `.image` class to `a`

```
<a class="image" href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg" class="" title="TITLE NEED SHOW ON HOVER" src=""/></a>
```

replace `data-content` with `title` in css:

```
.image:before {
    content: attr(title);
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:0;
    padding:4px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

finally, add this jQuery code:

```
$("a.image").each(function(){$(this).attr('title',$(this).find("img").attr('title'))});
```

Run it yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/51csqs0b/642/):

Comment: YEAH! Thanks genius!! I have I thought about doing that but I missed the part of Jquery!! yeah :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way. You just use :after pseudoelement on hover.
[Pure CSS solution](http://jsfiddle.net/51csqs0b/643/)

```
<a href="" class="img"></a>

.img{
  display: block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjsbh.jpg');
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.img:hover::after {
  content:'This is a description';
  position: absolute;
  width:100%; 
  height:20%;
  bottom:0; left:0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 }
```

You won't very specific. I hope it will help.
You can also make a tooltip.

Comment: Yes but in this way don't i need to write the content. I want use the attr(title) because i need to do with a lot of img with different title but same class. Anyway thanks!