# I'm trying achieve image hover effect using CSS. And I want the caption or Image title to be visible on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-transitions

I want *css* effect like in here https://olsonkundig.com/

I' am using:

```css
.swiper-slide-image:hover 
{  
    opacity: .8;
    transform: scale(1.04)
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Can anyone help me to add the title/caption with this?

Comment: Can't you find a more appropriate link for your example ? Wondering if that counts as a backlink ?!?

Comment: Hi, please check out http://demo.web10.online.  Here I just want to include the image title/caption on hover.

Comment: What is your html? I see lower down on the page you linked to in your comment what I suspect you are talking about. Please add more context or create a codepen so people are able to help you better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039330/show-title-tag-on-hover-inside-img

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you tried using transform 1.05 default and on hover 1.0?